# How much time a SOA composite should take in deployment?

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

How much time a SOA composite should take in deployment

Scenario:

1. Composite having 5-6 BPEL process.
2. it remote deployment by JDeveleoper
3. Considering network connectivity is good

for me its taking 15-20 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of things.

Taking that long is probably too long depending on the size of the processes.

Are you deploying to the same machine (I guess not by network conenctivity) which may indicate that your server does not have sufficient ram available and is doing a lot of disk swapping.  If possible increase your available ram for the machine, or stop other processes such as OSB or BAM if you have them running on the same server.

You need to allow about 2gb per process (so AdminServer and SOA takes at least 4g to operate effectively).

Comment: Yes agree, My processes are big . I dont have any other problem like(RAM, network). my worry is this is normal to take 20 minutes. or something is wrong...

Comment: Check your soa_server logs to see if anything untoward is happening.

Comment: Thanks,Now my BPEL process is taking 2-3 minutes in deployments. I Upgraded my environment to 11.1.1.4, I noticed while running the RCU i selected OPSS also. this schema containing all key stores and certificate. may be due to this my process were taking time in deployment.